# Lambda not supporting NLTK file size

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am writing a python script that analyses a piece of text and returns the data in JSON format. I am using NLTK, to analyze the data. Basically, this is my flow:

Create an endpoint (API gateway) -> calls my lambda function -> returns JSON of required data.

I wrote my script, deployed to lambda but I ran into this issue:

> Resource \u001b[93mpunkt\u001b[0m not found.   Please use the NLTK
>   Downloader to obtain the resource:
>
> \u001b[31m>>> import nltk
>     nltk.download('punkt')   \u001b[0m
>   Searched in:
>       - '/home/sbx_user1058/nltk_data'
>       - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
>       - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
>       - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
>       - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
>       - '/var/lang/nltk_data'
>       - '/var/lang/lib/nltk_data'

Even after downloading 'punkt', my script still gave me the same error. I tried the solutions here :

> [Optimizing python script extracting and processing large data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905075/optimizing-python-script-extracting-and-processing-large-data-files)

but the issue is, the nltk_data folder is huge, while lambda has a size restriction.

How can I fix this issue? 
Or where else can I use my script and still integrate API call?

I am using serverless to deploy my python scripts.

Comment: How big is your folder?

Comment: 1.4G, that's due to the nltk library and the standford library. Any ideas on how or where I can host the code ?

Comment: You don't need to download full nltk, If you just need `punkt` why not download just that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things that you can do:

1. The errors seems like the path is not being defined properly, maybe set it as an env Variable?

`sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('/var/task/nltk_data/')`

or this way

1. Once you run `nltk.download()`, then copy it to the root folder of your AWS lambda application. (Name the dir to be called "nltk_data".)
2. In the lambda function dashboard (in the AWS console), add `NLTK_DATA`=`./nltk_data` as a key-var Environment Variable.

---

2. reduce the size of the nltk downloads, since you won't be needing all of them.

   1. Delete all the zip files, keep only the needed section, for example: stopwords. That can be moved into: `save nltk_data/corpora/stopwords` and delete the rest.
   2. Or If you need tokenizers save to `nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt`. Most of these can be separately downloaded: `python -m nltk.downloader punkt`, then copy over the files.

Comment: How do you copy a file to the root folder of the AWS lambda application? Is this actually possible?