# NLTK module not found in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nltk, aws-serverless

I have successfully installed a package called [pronounceable](https://pypi.org/project/pronounceable/#description) for use in a Lambda function.
However it seems that the NLTK corpora `cmudict` is a dependpency which cannot be located.
This means that use of the command `import pronounceable` results in the following error.

```
>  Resource [93mcmudict[0m not found.   Please use the NLTK Downloader
> to obtain the resource:
> 
>   [31m>>> import nltk
>   >>> nltk.download('cmudict')   [0m   For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html
> 
>   Attempted to load [93mcorpora/cmudict[0m
> 
>   Searched in:
>     - './nltk_data'
>     - '/home/sbx_user1051/nltk_data'
>     - '/var/lang/nltk_data'
>     - '/var/lang/share/nltk_data'
>     - '/var/lang/lib/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
>     - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

**1.** Here is the code I used to install the package by way of creating a layer to apply to my Lambda function.

```
# STEP 1 
mkdir folder
cd folder
virtualenv v-env
source ./v-env/bin/activate
pip install pronounceable
deactivate 


# STEP 2
mkdir python
cd python
cp -r ../v-env/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/* .
cd ..
zip -r pronounceable_layer.zip python
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name pronounceable --zip-file fileb://panda_layer.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.6
```

I then simply selected and added the resultant layer to the Lambda function.
Then, as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920519/2781105), I placed the contents of `cmudict` (which I had manually downloaded to my local machine) into text file, within a folder called `nltk_data`, within the Lambda root folder.
I also attempted to alleviate the issue by adding an environment variable with the key/value `NLTK_DATA` & `./nltk_data`, and added `nltk.download('cmudict', download_dir="/var/task/nltk_data")` at the top of the function, to no avail.

**2.** I also used Cloud9 to open the NLTK file `data.py` and amend the path as per this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439958/2781105), due to a suspicion that `nltk.data.path.append()` was not working.

**3.** I also manually set the download path to `nltk.download('cmudict', download_dir='/tmp/')` as per this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815373/2781105), but this does not appear to work either.

I am at a loss as to what I need to do next.

**QUESTION**

What do I need to do to ensure that `cmudict` is available for use by nltk in my Lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

Posting answer in case it helps anyone experiencing a similar issue.

I resolved this issue by taking another look at the error message which suggests that the corpus file `cmudict` could not be found.
The full, *expected* path of this file is as follows:

`/var/task/nltk_data/corpora/cmudict/cmudict`

That is to say, the file `cmudict` needs to be placed in a folder called `cmudict`, which needs to be placed inside `corpora`, which needs to be placed inside `nltk_data`.

This can be achieved by creating the path in either of the following wasy:

1. Manually in the Lambda console (right click to create folder/file and paste corpora contents into the editor)
2. By creating the file structure `nltk_data/corpora/cmudict/cmudict` on a local machine, zipping the files and uploading the zip file to the Lambda editor.

[image]

[image]

NOTE - You may also need to amend the lambda code to reflect the expected path to the corpora, as follows:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import cmudict
nltk.data.path.append("/var/task/nltk_data")
```

You may also wish to set an environment variable and amend the file `data.py` as described in the answers linked to above.

Comment: Hello, my question is not related to problem for which this thread was created but something I noticed. I have seen the mention of user sbx_user1051 wherever lambda is involved and I tried to find who is this 'sbx_user1051' user but no luck. Any idea? it appears a user within docker container but not sure. I could not find information about this user itself but it is mentioned allover.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with your issue. All the best in finding a resolution.

Comment: How did you know `/var/task/nltk_data/corpora/cmudict/cmudict` is the *expected* path?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. 
`/var/task` is the lambda function folder (https://www.cloudtechsimplified.com/aws-lambda-layers/) so any dependencies that are placed in here need to be referenced using the appropriate path relative to your folder structure.